# Where are cron errors logged?

Tags: cron, scheduling, logs

If I setup `cron` jobs incorrectly they appear to silently fail. Where should I look for an error log to understand what went wrong?

Answer (score 138):

As others have pointed out, `cron` will email you the output of any program it runs (if there is any output). So, if you don't get any output, there are basically three possibilities:

1. `crond` could not even start a shell for running the program or sending email
2. `crond` had troubles mailing the output, or the mail was lost.
3. the program did not produce any output (including error messages)

Case 1. is very unlikely, but something should have been written in the cron logs.  Cron has an own reserved syslog facility, so you should have a look into `/etc/syslog.conf` (or the equivalent file in your distro) to see where messages of facility `cron` are sent.  Popular destinations include `/var/log/cron`, `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`.

In case 2., you should inspect the mailer daemon logs: messages from the Cron daemon usually appear as from `root@yourhost`.  You can use a `MAILTO=...` line in the crontab file to have cron send email to a specific address, which should make it easier to grep the mailer daemon logs.  For instance:

```
MAILTO=my.offsite.email@example.org
00 15 * * *  echo "Just testing if crond sends email"
```

In case 3., you can test if the program was actually run by appending another command whose effect you can easily check: for instance,

```
00 15 * * * /a/command; touch /tmp/a_command_has_run
```

so you can check if `crond` has actually run something by looking at
the mtime of `/tmp/a_command_has_run`.

Comment: Do these "emails" go in a file also? I'm using shared web hosting and don't think they'd know where to email me.

Comment: I appreciate the advice in case 3 to check if the command is even running.  In my case, cron wasn't running my job because I had recently changed the server's timezone and needed to restart the cron server so it would evaluate the cron times in the proper timezone.

Comment: Depending on your mail transfer agent, you may also find undelivered mails in a file called `dead.letter` in the root or respective user home directory.

Comment: What if a cronjob is set to run as a user other than root (username in /etc/crontab just after the time and before the executable path)? I'm getting emails for those run by root, but not from another user.

Comment: Same problem here. It helps running a simple shell script (sh, not bash), move to /tmp directory and launch the command you put in the crontab: you might receive on screen the same errors

Comment: the OP didn't specify he wanted to receive the output with mailing support. He simply asked where he can find the logs.

Answer (score 95):

You can always explicitly send the job output to a log file:

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/myjob > /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Keep in mind that this will supercede the mail behaviour that has been mentioned before, because crond iself won't receive any output from the job. If you want to keep that behaviour you should look into tee(1).

Comment: Why not use `>>` instead of `>`, so you don't overwrite the log file every time?

Comment: Sure! Any kind of I/O redirection will do, even `| /usr/bin/logger` if you wish, as cleverly suggested by Stefan. Pick your poison: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: cron created this log file `myjob.log` with 0 size as expected, but it logged to another file, where can I change this setting ?

Comment: What is the menaning of &1 at the end?

Comment: @Čamo as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/2053706) if you had `2>1` the instructions would mean, redirect `STDERR` to a file name called `1`. Since there's a `&` before the `1` treat the `1` as a file descriptor instead.

Comment: Make sure that the file to which you redirect output has proper conditions. If the cron task won't be able create the file or write to it your task will fail before it even starts.

Comment: This is what I do but it's growing tiresome. Crontab lines become a lot more complex than they should.

Answer (score 56):

If you aren't seeing the mails, you might be spamming root@yourcompany with the errors which can be quite annoying to the people who use that account for monitoring. Try sending the output to Syslog instead:

```
*/5 * * * * yourcronjob 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t yourtag
```

Then, wait for the cronjob to run and look for the error in /var/log/messages (or /var/log/user.log on some systems).

This works great for errors messages which are only 1-2 lines long, such as "yourcronjob: command not found". It also makes use of your existing syslog infrastructure (Logrotation, central syslogging, Splunk, etc.) It also reduces email spam to root.

It may not be a good solution if your cronjob generates hundreds of lines of output.

Comment: This is really good! I'm using for [our Mautic configuration at Lovia](https://about.lovia.life/docs/infrastructure/mautic-engineering/installing-mautic-in-ubuntu-vm/). Thanks Stefan!

Comment: I still do this, 10 years later!

Comment: Thanks! FYI: On Ubuntu 20 logs are available in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @Wirone: that file does contain CRON logs, but only the time and invocation line; no output. I have a 2-command crontab entry that runs perfectly from that echoed command line, but the second command doesn't run when cron executes it (the first does). Debugging this has been beyond frustrating.

Comment: Where has this been all my life?!

Answer (score 15):

You should get email from `crond` when the job either fails to run or when the job returns a nonzero exit code.  Try typing:

```
$ mailx
```

at the command prompt.

`mailx(1)` is the basic mail reading program on most every Unixlike system.  It is very primitive by modern standards, but you can pretty much count on it to always be available.  Other, better mail agents may be available, but there are enough of them that you never know which one is installed on some random machine you happen to be using.

Note that unless you have configured your system as an Internet email server, this mail subsystem is used only within the machine.  You can send email to and receive from other users on the machine, but you may not be able to send email out to the world, and email from the outer world certainly won't be able to come to your machine.

Comment: `sudo apt install -y mailutils`

Comment: `cat /var/mail/$USER` to view the messages in batch-mode

Comment: Also note `After you read your mail, mailx automatically places these messages in a storage file called $HOME/mbox`

Answer (score 8):

The default cron configuration will send you a mail with the output of your program.   If this fails, you could try wrapping your failing program in a shell script that ensures that the program does not fail, and you could further log the output.

This is a configurable setting on some cron implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Cron logs basic info to `/var/log/messages`, but mails any program output 
to the invoking user.

Comment: There's no `/var/log/messages` on my Ubuntu server (`4.4.0-128-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP`). Any idea why? I'va had a few cron jobs defined in `root`'s crontab for months (e.g. `apt autoremove`), but none seem to have been executed.

Comment: On ubuntu, you should look for /var/log/syslog
([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84633/where-is-var-log-messages))

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this thread a few years ago experiencing the same problems and just recently came across a solution to the above mentioned cases by Ricardo. The lack of an email is hard to detect (as you mentioned) and you certainly don't want to spam your root@yourcompany email. If interested check out [deadmanssnitch.com.](https://deadmanssnitch.com). This tool seems to solve the aforementioned cases. Seems pretty simple to use— just add the bit of code the tool gives you to your cronjob. If your job fails to run at a specified internal, you will be alerted. If you job starts running again you'll also be alerted.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful trick is to see what scripts are actually executed.

This is done with `run-parts -v --test /etc/cron.hourly/`

```
> /etc/cron.hourly//logrotate
```

If your script does not show up it will not be executed.

This btw only works for the scripts installed in the `/etc/cron.hourly` directory. It does not show you items that are set 
in your `crontab`.

Answer (score 2):

I know it may seem obvious, but it's worth verifying that you can actually run your script manually without Cron. My issue was that the script I was trying to run required authentication. When I ran it manually this was obvious, but I was not getting any email or other indication.

Answer (score 1):

I use `vixie-cron`, so I don't know if this applies to everything.  But I have a `dead.letter` file that contains all the output of the job.

In my `/root/` folder I have `crons.cron` which I set as my crontab by running `crontab /root/crons.cron`.  `dead.letter` will be created in `/root/` as well.

**Edit**
I just Google'd `dead.letter`, and it's an undeliverable mail.  It has nothing to do with cron apparently.  If you don't have mail set up correctly (like me), you'll have the file.

Answer (score 1):

For newbies, this could be a pain to debug. Be sure not to interchange the minute and the hour values. The minute comes first, then the hour. When you supply values less than 12 for each, it will accept them but may not work as expected or at all.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure this really answers the question.