# where is /var/log/messages

Tags: ubuntu, logs

I have several sources saying that `/var/log/messages` has system log message but I don't have that file (Ubuntu 11, Debian).

Is the messages file somewhere else now?  I tried using `locate` to look for it but didn't see it.

Comment: Does `/var/log/syslog` exist?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51265/where-is-var-log-messages

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Ubuntu no longer uses the `/var/log/messages` file by default. The same information is available in the file `/var/log/syslog`. You can [re-enable logging to `/var/log/messages`](http://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/tag/ubuntu-10-04-varlogmessages/) if you would like.

Syslog is a standard logging facility. It collects messages from various programs, including the kernel. It is usually configured to store these messages by default. How it stores these messages is generally distribution-dependant. `/var/log/messages` is generally used to store non-critical messages while `/var/log/syslog` stores everything, including critical and non-critical messages.