# Cronjob output to log

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm using a script for testing broadband speed and I would like to set up a cronjob for testing every n minutes and output to a file.
The command to launch it from a shell console and append to logfile prepending a line with the current date is

```
tespeed.py -w | sed -e "s/^/$(date +\"%d-%m-%y\ %T\"), /" >>tespeedlog.csv
```

But if I use this command in a cronjob something doesn't work; the syslog reports:

```
Sep 25 13:23:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[6719]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/tespeed/tespeed.py -w | sed -e "s/^/$(date +')
```

What shoud I check?

Comment: You need to escape the `%` characters with backslashes, see your `crontab(5)` man page for details.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged/330#330

Answer (score 4):

Create a wrapper script as there may be a problem with escaping date format. The problem seems to be with `%` character which may be interpreted as a new line specifier in some cron schedulers:

Put this to the file `/usr/local/bin/wrpr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tespeed.py -w | sed -e "s/^/$(date +\"%d-%m-%y\ %T\"), /" >> /tmp/tespeedlog.csv
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/wrpr.sh
```

And schedule it with cron (this will override the current user's crontab):

```
echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/wrpr.sh" | crontab
```

Otherwise, use `crontab -e` to add it to the current user's crontab.

Comment: @alzambo if it works, please accept this answer, that's the way to say thanks on the stack exchange sites.