# How do I know if crontab is working fine?

Tags: linux, cron

Is there a log of crontab for me to know if crontab is working fine? I am on Linux Mint 17.3.

What I have done:

1. ran `crontab -e` as root
2. it did not exist, so I chose nano editor and proceeded
3. entered this line `00 12 * * * /home/vlastimil/Development/bash/full-upgrade.sh`
4. saved and exited

My goal is to automate updates every single day at 12 hours (midday, not midnight). This thread is not about arguing the best way to achieve that.

I created `/home/vlastimil/Development/bash/full-upgrade.sh` file with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

And finally I have set 755 rights to the file.

I don't know how to test it. Will it work?

Comment: @thrig I completely forgot to tell you what Linux I am on. I have edited my question. I am on Mint 17.3.

Comment: to simply test cron just replace command part by `date  >> /tmp/cron-test.log` thus, you will now if it work and when.

Comment: @Archemar that's really a bad habit to get in to; put the log in `~` instead: `/tmp` is writable by everyone, and if someone were to notice that cron job, they could potentially at some point place a symlink there, and then (depending on security settings) root could be appending `date` to an arbitrary file...

Comment: @derobert, the **real** way is to look at the log, a dirty, quick and temporary way is as describe above. of course after you know, delete file and line from crontab.

Comment: @Archemar that quick and temporary way is made much safer by putting the log file in the user's home directory, not `/tmp`. "Temporary" things of course have a risk of being forgotten (a file logging the date once a day isn't likely to cause any problems—until someone malicious shows up).

Comment: @derobert To test it I decided to set it for 19:00 and this is output
Apr  6 19:00:01 vb-nb-mint CRON[12549]: (root) CMD (/home/vlastimil/Development/bash/full-upgrade.sh)
Apr  6 19:00:25 vb-nb-mint CRON[12548]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: @burian.vlastimil that sounds like it worked, but you might want to install an MTA (mail-transfer agent, i.e., a mail server) so that cron can send you the stderr of whatever you run.

Comment: @derobert yeah I would like to have it logged, how do I do this, shall I post another question?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Installing an MTA will get it mailed to you. If you want it logged, the easiest way is to pipe it to logger, or redirect it to a file. I suspect we already have examples of both on the site...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logs probably go to syslog, which varies depending on what syslog daemon is involved and how that is configured to log, start with

```
grep -r cron /etc/*syslog*
```

to find where and what is going on on the system, or per derobert under `systemd` the relevant command is

```
journalctl -b 0 _SYSTEMD_UNIT=cron.service
```

Adding a test cron job that touches a file (ideally not in `/tmp`, unless the vendor makes that per-user private, for security reasons) should also confirm whether cron is working or not, just be sure to eventually remove the test cron job before it fills up a partition or something silly.

Other usability and security pointers: some cron daemons can run scripts directly, in which case you can just copy the script into `/etc/cron.daily`, though this may not suit something that you do not want to run (with everything else!) at exactly the top of the hour. `root` running a script under a user's home directory could be very bad, as a compromise of that user account could then be leveraged to root access, or the script could needlessly fail if the home directory is on NFS or encrypted; move the script elsewhere to avoid this (`/root/bin`, or somewhere under `/usr/local` or `/opt` depending on the local filesystem preferences).

Even more pointers fall into the realm of shell script debugging, mostly to note that cron is not the shell; use `env` or `set` to see what is set under cron, check that `PATH` is correct, and etc. (One old and horrible linux kernel bug involved java daemons crashing but only if they were run from cron; that was fun to debug...)

Comment: in my case the log is in /var/log/syslog

Comment: journalctl: command not found