# crontab does not execute my bash script

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have created a simple executable script to move a file for me, as the name of the file is the date on each day, the script creates the file name and then moves the file. I want to schedule it to run every night using cron.

My script works when I run it in bash. It also works if I specify exactly the path and filename in the cron.

The problem occurs when I ask cron to run my script. It seems to me cron cannot run the subprocess to create the filename based on the date. my script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /home/folder1/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt /media/folder2/folder3
```

and this is how I set the job in crontab:

```
0 21 * * * /home/folder1/bash_text.txt
```

I have tried with $(which mv), with no luck. (tried both in the script and cron command)

```
0 21 * * * $(which mv) /home/folder1/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt /media/folder2/folder3
```

This only worked if I substituted the name of the file $(date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt with the actual file name.

```
0 21 * * * $(which mv) /home/folder1/2020-04-28.txt /media/folder2/folder3
```

Appreciate it if someone can help me, please. I am new to Linux as you can tell, so I am learning as I go, appreciate if you consider this in your replies.

Comment: Related: [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute \`date\` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment ...

**What is the error in each case?**

See here how to find cron errors: [Where are cron errors logged?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged)

**For the first setting**

Does `/home/folder1/bash_text.txt` really have execute permission?

If so, it should work.

**For the second setting**

The link provided by Kusalananda should work.

**In all cases**

The default shell for executing commands in crontab is `/bin/sh`. Maybe this is not suitable...

You can modify it like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

0 21 * * * command
```

For more information on using crontab:

```
$ man 5 crontab
```

Hope this helps.